# How to: Collapse Laravel collection into comma seperated string?

Tags: php, laravel

How to: Collapse Laravel collection into comma separated string?

```
dd($ids);

Illuminate\Support\Collection {#538 ▼
  #items: array:463 [▼
    0 => 30578786410269
    1 => 30578326028621
    2 => 30788548304669
    3 => 30788548607437
    4 => 30788592370221
    5 => 30788592672989
    6 => 30788592975757
    7 => 30492511411997
      ]
}
```

How would I turn this into a string like?:

```
30578786410269,30578326028621,30788548304669,30788548607437,30788592370221,30788592672989,30788592975757,30492511411997
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `implode` method that `Illuminate\Support\Collection` offers:

```
$imploded = $collection->implode(',');
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `implode`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-implode)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `implode()`

```
$data = $collection->implode(',');   // returns string
```

**OR** you can convert `collection` to `array`

```
$data = $collection->toArray();     // returns array
```